# Deleting records on a group by where condition?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm using SQL 2012 and I have this table:

```
Id  Ticket  LastChange
1   369151  2010-03-18 
2   369151  2010-03-18 
11  374173  2010-11-11 
12  374173  2010-11-11 
13  374173  2010-11-11 
54  374173  2014-01-13 
63  374503  2010-11-18 
64  393920  2010-10-15 
65  393920  2010-10-15 
69  393920  2010-10-19 
70  393920  2012-03-29 
71  404145  2011-03-04 
77  404145  2011-03-04 
78  404145  2011-03-10 
79  404145  2011-03-10 
80  404145  2011-03-10 
81  404145  2011-03-28 
82  404145  2011-03-28 
83  404145  2011-03-28 
84  404146  2011-03-04
```

I want to delete all records whose Ticket group hasn't had a change in the past x months. For example, If ticket 374173 has no LastChange in the past 6 months then delete all records in the table with ticket 374173.

I can do this with a ridiculous group query, join, subquery, subquery, delete but it seems overly complicated. I think partitioning over may be an easier way but am still new to TSQL. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using a subquery to get tickets to delete. Modify the "last 6 months" part to suit your exact needs.

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE Ticket IN
    (SELECT Ticket FROM table1
     GROUP BY Ticket
     HAVING MAX(LastChange) < DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE t1 FROM dbo.Table1 t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table1 t2
    WHERE t1.Ticket = t2.Ticket
    AND Datediff(Month, t2.LastChange, GETDATE()) <= 6 
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4df10/17/0)</kbd>

Actually `374173` is the only Ticket-Group with changes in the last 6 months, so all other records are deleted. That was confusing because you mentioned the opposite in the question.